# How to convert a Unity 3D application to Flash (*.swf)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, flash

There's a file which filename extension is *.unity3d. How can I convert this file into *.swf that I can play this game in my own computer?

Comment: File extensions are just designations for humans and default actions. The question is really "How to covert a Unity 3D application to Flash?" Try searching using that (or similar) phrasing. YMMV (and it might not be feasible as they are based on entirely different runtimes).

Comment: You don’t. That is like asking how you can convert a PlayStation game to play on your Xbox. It is theoretically doable, but unless you are the original developer, it is not practical in the slightest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.unity3d` files are from [Web Player builds](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WebPlayerDeployment.html).

They're meant to be embedded in a webpage, where the Unity3d Web Player plugin runs them in your browser.

The `.unity3d` file isn't meant to be opened, downloaded, or edited, and it is meant to protect proprietary assets  (in fact the only cases I see of people with `.unity3d` files without the matching project files are people who have extracted the files from a website for disallowed de-compilation).

Unity3D does have support for [Flash builds](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/flash-gettingstarted.html) as of the latest development cycle. But that support is [somewhat limited](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/flash-whatssupported.html), and it is a feature that has already been retired from the license sales line-up, and will not be present in the 5.x cycle for [various reasons](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/04/23/sunsetting-flash/), including the overall decline of Flash publishing.

If your intent is simply to run the game you can create a local html document referencing the `.unity3d` file to play the game in your browser. This is the default html document that Unity generates for a Web Player build. It assumes you have named the `.unity3d` file, `WebPlayer.unity3d`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Unity Web Player | WebPlayer</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function GetUnity() {
            if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") {
                return unityObject.getObjectById("unityPlayer");
            }
            return null;
        }
        if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") {
            unityObject.embedUnity("unityPlayer", "WebPlayer.unity3d", 960, 600);

        }
        -->
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        body {
            font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }
        a:link, a:visited {
            color: #000;
        }
        a:active, a:hover {
            color: #666;
        }
        p.header {
            font-size: small;
        }
        p.header span {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        p.footer {
            font-size: x-small;
        }
        div.content {
            margin: auto;
            width: 960px;
        }
        div.missing {
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            width: 193px;
        }
        div.missing a {
            height: 63px;
            position: relative;
            top: -31px;
        }
        div.missing img {
            border-width: 0px;
        }
        div#unityPlayer {
            cursor: default;
            height: 600px;
            width: 960px;
        }
        -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="header"><span>Unity Web Player | </span>WebPlayer</p>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="unityPlayer">
                <div class="missing">
                    <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">
                        <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="footer">&laquo; created with <a href="http://unity3d.com/unity/" title="Go to unity3d.com">Unity</a> &raquo;</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Inserting that in an empty html document with the `.unity3d` file correctly named should create a file you can open in your browser and run the game with.

However, keep in mind the original site could provide a more complex interface for the game's interaction with the page, in which case it would fail to run (though it may not fail immediately).

Unity3d allows the game to communicate with the page it's embedded in through javascript. You generally cannot replicate the code the original page provides locally without a deep understanding of the original project (which would imply you have access to the project, making this all unnecessary).

Comment: So how can I convert the *.unity3d files into *.swf?

Comment: I thought the answer made it clear, but you can't: "The .unity3d file isn't meant to be opened, downloaded, or edited, and it is meant to protect proprietary assets". If you're just trying to run/share it you can try using the html file to run it as-is, but you can't modify it.